# How to merge duplicated keys in array of dictionaries python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have an array of dictionaries in Python:

```
[
   {'id':1, 'name':'foo', 'email':'foo@foo.foo'},
   {'id':2, 'name':'foo', 'email':'foo1@foo1.foo1'},
   {'id':3, 'name':'bar', 'email':'bar@bar.bar'},
   {'id':3, 'name':'bar', 'email':'bar1@bar1.bar1'},
   {'id':3, 'name':'bar', 'email':'bar2@bar2.bar2'},
 ]
```

Expected Output:

```
[
   {'id':1, 'name':'foo', 'email':['foo@foo.foo', 'foo1@foo1.foo1']},
   {'id':2, 'name':'bar', 'email':['bar@bar.bar', 'bar1@bar1.bar1', 'bar2@bar2.bar2]}
]
```

is there any short way to achieve expected output?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate and group items with the same name

```
res = {}
unique_id = 1

for d in records:
    if d['name'] in res:
        res[d['name']]['email'].append(d['email'])
    else:
        res[d['name']] = {'id':unique_id, 'name':d['name'], 'email':[d['email']]}
        unique_id+=1


>>> print(*res.values(), sep='\n')
{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo', 'email': ['foo@foo.foo', 'foo1@foo1.foo1']}
{'id': 2, 'name': 'bar', 'email': ['bar@bar.bar', 'bar1@bar1.bar1', 'bar2@bar2.bar2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is a perfect application of [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). To solve it, you simply use `groupby` to group the entries in your list by the key `"name"`, then format the results however you want.

Here's concretely how to do that:

```
from itertools import groupby

d = [
   {'id':1, 'name':'foo', 'email':'foo@foo.foo'},
   {'id':2, 'name':'foo', 'email':'foo1@foo1.foo1'},
   {'id':3, 'name':'bar', 'email':'bar@bar.bar'},
   {'id':3, 'name':'bar', 'email':'bar1@bar1.bar1'},
   {'id':3, 'name':'bar', 'email':'bar2@bar2.bar2'},
 ]

result = []
# if the keys you want to group by aren't consecutive
d = sorted(d, key=lambda x: x["name"])

for idx, val in enumerate(groupby(d, key=lambda x: x["name"])):
    result.append(
        {"id": idx + 1,
         "name": val[0],
         "email": [x["email"] for x in val[1]]}
    )
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'foo', 'email': ['foo@foo.foo', 'foo1@foo1.foo1']},
 {'id': 2,
  'name': 'bar',
  'email': ['bar@bar.bar', 'bar1@bar1.bar1', 'bar2@bar2.bar2']}]
```

Comment: what if entries with the same name are not all consecutive?